# Database Cleaner: Clean vs truncation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, database-cleaner

What is the difference between the following?

- DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
- DatabaseCleaner.clean

What i'm trying to figure out is what is the best way to clean up a before(:all) hook in my tests (performance wise) using database cleaner. My before(:all) hook just creates a ton of factories and creates some associations between them. Currently, i'm just loading them all in a before(:each) not having to worry about the cleanup afterwards.

My current strategy looks like:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = example.metadata[:js] ? :truncation : :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

So in addition to my previous question, what should my after(:all) look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the difference between the following?
>
> - DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
> - DatabaseCleaner.clean

The difference is pretty straightforward: in the first case you're telling `DatabaseCleaner` to clean your db now with `truncation` strategy, and in the second case `DatabaseCleaner` will clean your db using currently configured strategy.

I think your setup is pretty good already. Since creating a ton of factories (as you said) in `before(:all)` hook is quite rare, you just need to add to that specific test `after(:all)` hook to put the db back to stable state.

Cleaning with transaction won't work, since `before(:all)` [is not wrapped](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions) in transaction.
You're left with 2 options here:

1. `after(:all) { DatabaseCleaner.with(:truncation) }`
2. `after(:all) { DatabaseCleaner.with(:deletion) }`

In order to choose between these two, as [documentation clearly states](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#what-strategy-is-fastest), you have to measure and choose what's fastest for you, or just pick some if it doesn't matter.

Comment: So for my strategy, is DatabaseCleaner.clean in my after(:each) cleaning the strategy set in my before(:each)?

Comment: Awesome thanks that's exactly what I was trying to figure out